# How to implement Role based restrictions/permissions in react redux app?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, user-permissions, role-based-access-control

I have a React-Redux-KoaJs application with multiple components. I have few user roles as well. Now i want to display few buttons, tables and div to only specific roles and hide those from others. Please remember i dont want to hide the whole component, but just a part of the components. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can check the role or permission in every component as @Eudald Arranz proposed. Or you can write a component that will checks permissions for you. For example:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const ShowForPermissionComponent = (props) => {
    const couldShow = props.userPermissions.includes(props.permission);
    return couldShow ? props.children : null;
};

ShowForPermissionComponent.propTypes = {
    permission: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    userPermissions: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    userPermissions: state.user.permission //<--- here you will get permissions for your user from Redux store
});

export const ShowForPermission = connect(mapStateToProps)(ShowForPermissionComponent);
```

and then you can use this component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ShowForPermission } from './ShowForPermission';

cons MyComponent = props => {
   return (
        <div>
            <ShowForPermission permission="DELETE">
                <button>Delete</button>
            </ShowForPermission>
        </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really appreciate the answer. But i figured out an alternate approach, which i am going to put in the answers really soon. Do check it out. Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This approach has performance drawback. Imagine you have 150+ or more UI elements in your page that needs to checked for permissions (buttons, selects, checkboxes, menu options, tabs, etc etc). With your approach you end up calling `props.userPermissions.includes` method 150+ times or more. You're iterating the same array for every element. It may slowdown your app.

Comment: @Green yes, you are right. You can save your permissions in ES6 `Set`, or if you don't like to use mutable collections, you could use `Set` from immutable.js. Or you could just use an `Object` where keys - permission names and values - whatever you want.

Answer (score 16):

Be careful with that. If the actions of some roles are important you should always validate them at your backend. It's easy to change the values stored in redux at frontend allowing malicious use of the roles if there is no proper validation.

If you want to proceed on a possible approach is this:

- Save the roles at your reducer
- Bind the reducer to the component:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { user_roles } = state;
  return { user_roles };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent);
```

- Then at your component, you can check the user_roles and render the actions accordingly:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.user_roles.role === "YOUR_ROLE_TO_CHECK" && <ActionsComponent />}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This will render the `ActionsComponent` only when the role is equal to the desired one.

Again, always validate the roles at your backend!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is one approach to follow but if you have a lot of components and elements to show and hide then it becomes really hard to keep track of it. I have figured out an alternate approach which i am going to post in answers real soon. Do check it out. Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Harshit it has been 3 years now. Where is your alternate approach that you were providing _real soon_

Answer (score 12):

The best practice to solve this Problem is, simply prevent the app to generate unnecessary routes, rather checking current user role on each route it is great to generate only the routes that user have access.

**So The Normal reouting is:**
To control the whole view:

```js
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/Account" component={PrivateAccount} />
      <Route path="/Home" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
  export default App;
);
```

**Routing based on user role:**

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
   // other imports ...
   const App = () => (
      <BrowserRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
        {
          this.props.currentUser.role === 'admin' ?
            <>
          <Route path="/Account" exact component={PrivateAccount} />
          <Route path="/Home" exact component={Home} />
            </> 
            : 
          <Route path="/Home" exact component={Home} />
        }
        <Route component={fourOFourErroPage} />

        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
      
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentUser: state.currentUser,
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

So the user with an Admin role will have access to the Account page and for other users will have access to the Home page Only! and if any user try to access to another route, the 404 page error will appear.
I hope I've given a helpful solution.

For advanced details about this approach you can check this repo on github: [Role-based-access-control with react](https://github.com/umair-khanzada/role-based-access-control)

**To hide just a presentational component:**

```js
{this.props.currentUser.role === 'admin' && <DeleteUser id={this.props.userId} /> }
```

Comment: It sounds good for routes but in every component there might be stuff which is shown to user to the basis of their role.

Comment: Exactly, for that you can just hide the presentational component as as mentioned above.

Comment: This response is not directly related to what was asked for

Answer (score 6):

So, I have figured out there is an alternate and easy approach to implement role based access (RBAC) on frontend.

In your redux store state, create a object called permissions (or you can name it whatever you like) like this:

```
const InitialState = {
  permissions: {}
};
```

Then on your login action, setup the permissions that you want to provide like this:

```
InitialState['permissions'] ={
  canViewProfile: (role!=='visitor'),
  canDeleteUser: (role === 'coordinator' || role === 'admin')
  // Add more permissions as you like
}
```

In the first permission you are saying that you can view profile if you are not a visitor.
In the second permission you are saying that you can delete a user only if you are an admin or a coordinator.
and these variables will hold either true or false on the basis of the role of the logged in user. So in your store state u will have a permission object with keys that represent permissions and their value will be decided on the basis of what your role is.

Then in your component use the store state to get the permission object. You can do this using connect like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  permissions : state.permissions
}
```

and then connect these props to your Component like:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(ComponentName);
```

Then you can use these props inside your component on any particular element which you want to show conditionally like this:

```
{(this.props.permissions.canDeleteUser) && <button onClick={this.deleteUser}>Delete User</button>}
```

The above code will make sure that the delete user button is rendered only if you have permissions to delete user i.e. in your store state permissions object, the value of canDeleteUser is true.

That's it, you have appplied a role based access. You can use this approach as it is easily scalable and mutable, since you will have all permsisions according to roles at one place.

Hope, this helps! If i missed out something please help me in the comments. :-)

Comment: > _it is easily scalable and mutable_
It is not easily scalable. It is good only for simple use cases like yours - a couple of roles and a couple of permissions. Anything more complicated than that (e.g different stages of the app with different permissions for roles on each stage) and you will end up having this: `a && b || c && d || e` which is hard to manage.

Comment: @Green so what is the best way to manage scalable user roles and permissions in SPAs and possibly sync with the backend too?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this in this [rbac-react-redux-aspnetcore repository](https://github.com/foyzulkarim/rbac-react-redux-aspnetcore/tree/master/client/src).
If someone wants to use Redux with Context API, then the below code snippet can be helpful.

```
export const SecuedLink = ({ resource, text, url }) => {

  const userContext = useSelector(state => {
    return state.userContext;
  });    

  const isAllowed = checkPermission(resource, userContext);
  const isDisabled = checkIsDisabled(resource, userContext);

  return (isAllowed && <Link className={isDisabled ? "disable-control" : ""} to={() => url}>{text}</Link>)
}


const getElement = (resource, userContext) => {
    return userContext.resources
        && userContext.resources.length > 0
        && userContext.resources.find(element => element.name === resource);
}

export const checkPermission = (resource, userContext) => {
    const element = getElement(resource, userContext);
    return userContext.isAuthenticated && element != null && element.isAllowed;
}

export const checkIsDisabled = (resource, userContext) => {
    const element = getElement(resource, userContext);
    return userContext.isAuthenticated && element != null && element.isDisabled;
}
```

To use the above snippet, we can use it like below

```
  <SecuedLink resource='link-post-edit' url={`/post-edit/${post.id}`} text='Edit'></SecuedLink>
  <SecuedLink resource='link-post-delete' url={`/post-delete/${post.id}`} text='Delete'></SecuedLink>
```

So, depending on the role, you can not only show/hide the element, but also can enable/disable them as well. The permission management is fully decoupled from the react-client and managed in database so that you don't have to deploy the code again and again just to support new roles and new permissions.

Comment: You haven't shown how the permissions are set

Comment: that is in the server side code (stored in MS SQL server)

Answer (score 0):

This post is very exactly what you need without any library:

[react-permissions-and-roles](https://isamatov.com/react-permissions-and-roles/)

Answer (score 0):

The steps can be

- Maintain a json structure that holds list of menus and submenus.
- Iterate the original json structure and for each menu && submenus

  - Check logged in user's role

    - Accumulate new json menu list that you can render.

For efficiency, You can use react-redux to store and re-use this newly constructed json menu.

Just to keep in mind that everything is client side. You still need to implement proper authorisation mechanism for each api request to prevent unauthorised access for each menu it has to offer.